# Is Entropy Backwards?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

Is it weird that everything with a gradient goes from high to low except for entropy?

High pressures try to fill in low pressures, high temp goes to low temp, osmosis happens from high to low, etc. etc. There are all these examples from things going from high gradient to low gradient to reach equilibrium... except entropy. Are we thinking about entropy wrong or is the key actually because the aforementioned processes are striving for equilibrium, but entropy isn’t in the same way?

Comment: First of all, you have named two _intensive_ state variables (not depending on the system size), pressure and temperature, and are attempting to compare them to entropy, which is an _extensive_ state variable (it depends on the system size). This is why you're finding it hard to talk about gradients when it comes to entropy. To make a proper comparison, you should really use the intensive equivalent, _entropy density_. It should be clear that there can be entropy density gradients wherever the local entropy density varies.

Comment: That’s a important point. I didn’t know the differences between intensive and extensive state variables. How do these comparisons hold up using entropy density?

Comment: "High pressures try to fill in low pressures" - this means that a vessel at high pressure and a vessel at low pressure, when connected together and isolated, will equalize their pressure in equilibrium. The same goes for the other examples, and the same happens with entropy density - a system at high entropy density and a system of low entropy density will equalize their entropy density at equilibrium when connected to each other and isolated.

Comment: It's also not necessarily true, in general, that gradients vanish at equilibrium, nor is it even true that they must decrease. For example, take some gas, initially at uniform pressure, that is then placed in a gravitational field. As it equilibrates, the gas develops a pressure gradient, with higher pressure at the bottom and lower pressure at the top. Here, the process of coming into equilibrium has taken the system from zero pressure gradient to nonzero pressure gradient.

Comment: Oh brilliant! So it does work expected when considering the right scope. Do you have an example or some sort of analogy of entropy density I could process what that it really means?

Comment: I'm not sure that I know enough about non-equilibrium thermodynamics to construct a rigorous example (hence why I'm leaving these as comments for now), and what I said may not even be true in all cases (i.e. the entropy density may not actually equalize at equilibrium, for the same reason that the pressure does not always equalize at equilibrium).

Comment: Why don't you try a few simple modeling calculations to see how this plays out?  For example, determine the entropy change when a hot body is put into contact with a cold body, and they are allowed to equilibrate at an intermediate temperature.  What is the change in entropy?  Positive or negative?

Comment: You *are* aware, aren't you, that an entire class of information science users utilize "negentropy" ~ information, instead, which decreases spontaneously-- no?  You are merely marvelling at a sign and a convention?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed entropy can be confusing (no pun intended). Chapman's examples all involve processes and the disequilibrium that cause them. Entropy is not a process, but a state function just like temperature, pressure, internal energy, enthalpy, etc.

LightingNe002 statement that "not all processes result in entropy increase" is correct if one looks only at the "system" or only at the "surroundings". However, all real processes are irreversible and result in an overall increase in entropy (system + surroundings).

I like to use the following heat transfer example to show the connection between entropy and disequilibrium (in this case, thermal disequilibrium). It involves a decrease in entropy of the system, an increase in entropy of the surroundings, but always in increase in the total entropy (system plus surroundings).

Consider a system H (a hot body) and its surroundings C (a cold body). Further consider both H and C to be thermal reservoirs, that is, they are so massive that a heat transfer between them doesn’t change their temperatures. The temperature of H is TH and the temperature of C is TC. We bring the bodies together and desire to transfer heat Q from H to C. Since the temperature of either does not change, the heat transfer occurs isothermally.  Let’s look at the entropy changes:

For Body A (System):  ΔSA = -Q/TH (a drop in entropy)

For Body B (Surroundings):  ΔSB = +Q/TC (a rise in entropy)

The total entropy change:  ΔSTot = ΔSA + ΔSB

Then for any TH > TC:     Q/T C - Q/TH > 0

In order for the total entropy change to approach zero, the temperature difference must approach zero.  This results in the heat transfer rate approaching zero and the time it takes to transfer Q infinitely long. In order for the total entropy change to actually equal zero, the temperatures would have to be the same- but if that were the case we would have no heat transfer at all!

Answer (score -1):

Entropy is definitely one of most confusing entities in the realm of Thermodynamics(at least I fount it to be so).Coming to the heart of the matter, not all processes result in an increase in entropy. For example when a stretched rubber band comes back to original form entropy decreases. And there are infinitely more processes where Entropy decreases.

The thing is this is how we defined Entropy. We could have  named it something else and decided that when entropy decreases this quantity decreases.Entropy increases even though pressure tends to decrease as we approach equilibrium because we made it like that.

Also the sole purpose of these quantities is to help us determine spontaneity,feasibility,energy change,etc associated with a given process.Reaching Equilibrium for a system means maximization of Entropy,bringing Gibbs Free Energy to zero,having no Temp difference w.r.t surroundings and having Chemical Equilibrium.
And if you think equilibrium means minimization of all variables then delete this thought. Think about unstable equilibrium to justify my previous statement.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I get so frustrated when I hit that “it’s just defined that way” wall in physics.